# Sending String[] Array over J2ME Socket Connection using ObjectOuputStream

Tags: sockets, java-me

I am trying to send a `String[]` array in j2me using `ObjectOUputStream`, but i keep getting this error,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an HTTP URL

Here is my code:

```
    OutputStream os=null;
    HttpConnection hc= null;
    ObjectOutputStream oj=null;

    //get the URL
    String serverURL=entry.getUrl();

    hc=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(serverURL, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
    hc=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(serverURL);


    hc.setRequestMethod (HttpConnection.POST);
    hc.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hc.setRequestProperty ("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
    hc.setRequestProperty ("Content-Language", "en-US");

    System.out.println ("Posting to the URL: " + entry.getVectorParams());

    //open the output stream to send the post parameters
    //os=hc.openOutputStream();

    oj=(ObjectOutputStream)hc.openOutputStream();
    //writing post parameters
    String[] bg=entry.getVectorParams();

    oj.writeObject(bg);
```

Please give a suggestion.

I checked my URL, it is correct and regarding Connector.open(), i pasted it twice here, not in my actual code. Is there anything else that I am doing wrong?

The `System.out.println("Posting to the URL: " + entry.getVectorParams())`, this only prints the post parameters, I have the serverurl passed in here:

```
String serverURL=entry.getUrl();
hc=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(serverURL, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
```

My server URL is : `http://localhost:8080/Web/gServer.jsp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your `serverURL` variable must not be a valid URL.  Try printing it out, and checking.

You have this debug statement:

```
System.out.println ("Posting to the URL: " + entry.getVectorParams());
```

but that is printing out the params, not the url.  You should print out the `serverURL` variable.

Also, you are calling `Connector.open()` twice in a row.  There's no need for that.

**Update:** I also think there could be a problem with the way you're writing the POST parameters to your connection's `OutputStream`.  I wouldn't use an `ObjectOutputStream`.  See [something like this](http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2007/04/http-post-from-j2me-midlet.html) for an example of making J2ME POST calls.  Basically, you make a `String` of the POST parameters, separated by `&`, and then use `String.getBytes()` to convert to a `byte[]` for writing to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Yes, i checked my URL, it is correct and regarding Connector.open(), i pasted it twice here, not in my actual code. Is there anything else that i am doing wrong. The system.out.println("Posting to the URL: " + entry.getVectorParams()), this only prints the post parameters, i have the serverurl passed in here String serverURL=entry.getUrl(); hc=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(serverURL, Connector.READ_WRITE, true); My server URL is : http://localhost:8080/Web/gServer.jsp

Comment: Can you post the **exact** URL for us to see?

Comment: when you use the URL in the **code**, are you adding `"http://"` on to the front of it?  have you tried that?  I can't tell, with Stack Overflow's comment formatting, if you included that, or not.

Comment: So, I noticed that the hostname in your URL is `localhost`.  Is that really correct?  Are you running this app on a desktop **simulator**?  If you're pointing at `http://localhost:8080`, then you have an application server installed on your J2ME device?  I'm wondering if the device detects the localhost hostname, and assumes that to be wrong, because some J2ME phones might not allow local *services*.  Can you tell us which device, or simulator, you're running on?  Have you tried another URL, that is not on `localhost`?

Comment: when i dont use ObjectOutputStream, it works fine and i can send my parameters to the URL, but when i use the ObjectOutputStream, this error pops up. I am accessing the server on my localhost, that is my server side code is there on my machine, and i connect the emulator to it by sending the mobile form parameters.

Comment: **Why** are you using ObjectOutputStream at all?  See my update above.

Comment: @ARAZA You can't convince me that using/not using an ObjectOutputStream changes an invalid URL exception. There is something wrong with your observations here.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant, when i said it works fine when not using ObjectOutputStream, i use OutputStream.write instead by looping through my array and then send the post parameter individually till the lenght of the array. But i wanted to try sending an entire array not individual array element each time. So, the only way of doing that was to use ObjectOutputStream, which allows me to use writeObject(array) method and pass an array into it.

Comment: Just because you use `OutputStream`, that doesn't mean you need to send POST parameters individually.  You can still send a set of all parameters in one `write()` call.  There will not be multiple network calls, and any additional delay in your network transaction.  The more important factor is that I don't think the binary format of `ObjectOutputStream` is correct for an HTTP POST.  Even though the data type is `byte[]`, that doesn't mean it's formatted correctly.